Using pvlib iotools read_tmy3 on multiple years of data at once
I am trying to look at multiple years of precipitation data at once for use with pvlib.soiling.kimber. The tmy3 import works just fine for one year of data but if I add additional 8760 data below it doesn't work, example error:
"ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer"
I've tried copying the same formatting for the date, time, and data but still am getting the above error. Can read_tmy3 work with multiple years of data? If not, what's the best way to accomplish this? I want to run the kimber on 20 years of hourly precipitation data.
I tried to ensure the formatting of the additional rows was identical to the rows above, even copy pasting the original again, for example.

I don't immediately see anything in the source code that limits it to just one year (although TMY files by definition are one year). Source code for the read_tmy3 function can be found here: https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pvlib/iotools/tmy.html#read_tmy3. You might have to write your own custom parser, but with the help of the source code that should be relatively easy
